# Interactive Python shell

Tags: python

This might be something pretty minor to ask but it just puzzles me a lot and makes me want to find out why..
Whenever I try print() in interactive python shell after a loop through a list it always comes back with an error but it is totally fine when having it performed in a file/module manner.
Anyone knows why?

```
>>> z = [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
>>> total = 0
>>> for i in z:
...     total += i
... print(total)
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    print(total)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thanks.

Comment: in interactive mode you need a blank line to complete the statement

Answer (score 1):

It's expecting a blank line to signal the end of the nested block; press `<enter>` a second time before your `print(total)` command

Answer (score 1):

You need to press enter one more time - it is invalid syntax because you are still in the for loop and an indent is missing:

```
>>> z = [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
>>> total = 0
>>> for i in z:
...   total += i
...
>>> print(total)
20
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought Python uses indentation to tell if it is still inside the loop. At least it is the way how Python is performed in the file/module manner.